Why is the audio output of docking station not detected when connected a screen to the docking station?
I bought this docking station:

SZPACMATE: 4,2 4,2 su 5 stelle (6.137)
HUB USB C, Docking Station 12 in 1 con 4K HDMI, VGA, 3*USB 2.0, USB3.0, USB C Data, PD3.0, Porta Ethernet RJ45, SD/TF, AUX da 3,5 mm, Compatibile con MacBook Pro/Air, Altri Dispositivi di Tipo C)

And when I connect a display (HP L2208w) with VGA to the docking, the jack of docking station does not work.
From what I understand the audio output of the docking station is like the audio output of a screen with HDMI.

And by connecting the screen, which is detected also an audio output, the jack of the docking station is substituted by the audio output of the second screen.

